# Visual Studio 2013 Autocompletion of VB.NET Properties

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, autocomplete

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2013 on my PC and, though the majority of the IDE is great, it seems that the auto-completion of VB.NET properties does not work as it used to.

Previously (VS 2008) after typing something like:

```vb
Public Property Test() As String
```

...and pressing <kbd>Return</kbd>, the body of the Property would be autocompleted for me...

```vb
Public Property Test() As String
    Get

    End Get
    Set(value As String)

    End Set
End Property
```

In VS2013, however, this doesn't seem to be the case anymore, though if I type:

```vb
Public ReadOnly Property Test() As String
```

..and press <kbd>Return</kbd>, the property is finished for me.

Am I missing something here, or is this how it's going to be from now on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS 2010 (what i am using) the behaviour is the same as in VS 2013. The latter is a readonly property which **must have** and **can only have** a getter, so this is not valid:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Test() As String
```

That's why VS automatically adds it if you press <kbd>Return</kbd>. If you want the same behaviour with a "normal"/[auto-Implemented property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx)  you have to begin a `Get` like:

```
Public Property Test() As String
Get
```

if you now press <kbd>Return</kbd> you get the full body:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Test() As String
    Get

    End Get
    Set(value As String)

    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Ah! That's the one. Seems a bit of an oddity but is workable. Thanks Tim.

Comment: Auto implemented properties were a new language feature. If all your property did was to read to/write from an internal variable, then they remove all of the boiler plate - you get the same result with less typing. For fun, try to declare a variable with the name _test in a module with an auto implemented property named Test - you'll see that behind the scenes the compiler has created a backing variable "_test", and doesn't like you manually declaring one!

Comment: Here's a link with more information - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yes - I was going to, but had a train to catch and couldn't close the answer for another 5 minutes! ;o)

Comment: @KevinO'Donovan: Thanks Kevin - I always like to handle that kind of stuff myself, I must admit. Doing this allows me to add events and the like in, or more complex code to handle problematic values, for instance.